# Excel - how to split cell with delimiter

Tags: excel

i want to split the value of the excel cell in two values, but still have them only in one cell. I mean: i have cells with for example 40/50. Many of them. I want to count sum of numbers in front of / and the second sum of numbers behind /. Is it somehow possible without splitting those numbers in two different columns?
thx

Comment: 1) does all your numbers have format `x/y`? 2) is it correct, that you want to get two numbers: sum of all `x` from each cell and sum of all `y` from each cell?

Comment: yes and yes - as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your cells in range `A1:A4` are in format `x/y`,

- to sum all `x` use: `=SUM(1*LEFT(A1:A4,FIND("/",A1:A4)-1))`
- to sum all `y` use: `=SUM(1*RIGHT(A1:A4,LEN(A1:A4)-FIND("/",A1:A4)))`

both formulas are array formulas, so you should press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate them.

[image]